# Changing Format of date (left to right as per image)

Tags: excel, vba

[image: [Date in differing formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20rsH.png)]

I have these two date formats, would prefer it in the latter, i.e. on the right hand side.

My issue is that when the date is on the left it doesn't show up in other formula in my workbook and does when the format is on the right.

At the moment i'm using

```
= Format(Now(), "dd\/mm\/yyyy")
```

To enter todays date.

Double clicking in the cell work and text to columns ->finish both work but i don't know how to add that to my VBA.

Comment: When a cell value is naturally left aligned it's a  good indication that Excel is treating the value as text, when it is right aligned it's a numeric value.  Your left aligned dates don't show up as Excel is treating it as text and not a date.  The [Format Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-function-6f29d87b-8761-408d-81d3-63b9cd842530) will return text and not a date.  To format as a date don't use a formula, use cell formatting - right-click the cell, select _Format Cells_ and format as a date.

Comment: One way to format a _text_ date as a real date is to multiple the value by 1 and then format the cell as a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
 With cell_ref
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Value = Date
 End With
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace your current FORMAT function with this formula: =TODAY()

Comment: `TODAY()` is not a VBA function.

Comment: Hahaha I looked at the screenshot and thought this was a cell formula. I always seem to mix up the FORMAT and TEXT functions :-)